How can I keep the input in that specific form?
I am trying to allow the user to add points using the addPointBtn but I have no idea on how to keep the points to that specific class. like I managed to keep the points to that class when they add class but for some reason when I edit, it does not continue to add up the points and that's the part I'm stuck on.
Don't worry about the way the form-container is showing the points, I just wanted something on the container so that I know it works.
What I want is that if the user wants to edit and add more points, I dont want the points that is already there to be overwrite which is what is going on here.


const addOrUpdatePointsForm = () => {
  const dataArrIndex = cgFormData.findIndex(item => item.id === pointFormData.id);

  const pointAdd = document.querySelectorAll(".point-input");

  let totalPoints = 0;

  pointAdd.forEach(input => {
    const getValue = parseFloat(input.value);
    if (!isNaN(getValue)) {
      totalPoints += getValue;
    };
  });

  const cgFormObj = {
    // split does this - "WALK DOG" -> "walk-dog"
    // the ${} turns the whole expression into strings
    id: `${nameInput.value.toLowerCase().split(" ").join("-")}`,
    name: nameInput.value,
    PointAMinNum: PointAMinNum.value,
    PointAMaxNum: PointAMaxNum.value,
    PointBMinNum: PointBMinNum.value,
    PointBMaxNum: PointBMaxNum.value,
    PointCMinNum: PointCMinNum.value,
    PointCMaxNum: PointCMaxNum.value,
    PointDMinNum: PointDMinNum.value,
    PointDMaxNum: PointDMaxNum.value,
    PointFMinNum: PointFMinNum.value,
    PointFMaxNum: PointFMaxNum.value,
    points: totalPoints,
  };

  if (dataArrIndex === -1) {
    // "unshift" adds the parameter to the beginning of the array
    // but i want to put it at back instead of front using "push"
    cgFormData.push(cgFormObj);
  } else {
    // allows the edited input to be changed when submit
    cgFormData[dataArrIndex] = cgFormObj;
  };

  alert(`Points: ${totalPoints}`);

  updateFormContainer();

  pointReset();

};

const updateFormContainer = () => {
  cgFormContainer.innerHTML = "";

  cgFormData.forEach(({
    id,
    name,
    PointAMinNum,
    PointAMaxNum,
    PointBMinNum,
    PointBMaxNum,
    PointCMinNum,
    PointCMaxNum,
    PointDMinNum,
    PointDMaxNum,
    PointFMinNum,
    PointFMaxNum,
    points
  }) => {
    cgFormContainer.innerHTML += `
            <div class="form-holder" id="${id}">
                <p><strong>Name: </strong>${name}</p>
                <p><strong>A-Max: </strong>${PointAMaxNum}</p>
                <p><strong>F-Min: </strong>${PointFMinNum}</p>
                <p><strong>Points: </strong>${points}</p>
                <button onclick="editPointForm(this)" type="button" class="btn">Edit</button>
                <button onclick="deletePointForm(this)" type="button" class="btn">Delete</button>
            </div>
        `;
  });
};


const editPointForm = (button) => {
  const dataArrIndex = cgFormData.findIndex(item => item.id === button.parentElement.id);

  // to keep track of what is being edit
  pointFormData = cgFormData[dataArrIndex];

  let thisFormPoints = 0;

  const pointInput = document.querySelectorAll(".point-input");
  pointInput.forEach(input => {
    const getPoint = parseFloat(input.value);
    if (!isNaN(getPoint)) {
      thisFormPoints = getPoint;
    };
  });

  // put in the input from that form
  nameInput.value = pointFormData.name;
  PointAMinNum.value = pointFormData.PointAMinNum;
  PointAMaxNum.value = pointFormData.PointAMaxNum;
  PointBMinNum.value = pointFormData.PointBMinNum;
  PointBMaxNum.value = pointFormData.PointBMaxNum;
  PointCMinNum.value = pointFormData.PointCMinNum;
  PointCMaxNum.value = pointFormData.PointCMaxNum;
  PointDMinNum.value = pointFormData.PointDMinNum;
  PointDMaxNum.value = pointFormData.PointDMaxNum;
  PointFMinNum.value = pointFormData.PointFMinNum;
  PointFMaxNum.value = pointFormData.PointFMaxNum;
  thisFormPoints = pointFormData.points;


  // replace the button text
  nextBtn.innerText = "Update";
  nextBtn.type = "submit";

  addCurrentGradeClassBtn.classList.add("hidden");
  cgFormContainer.classList.add("hidden");
  pointGradeForm.classList.remove("hidden");

  cgNameInput.classList.remove("hidden");
};


const pointReset = () => {

  nameInput.value = "";
  PointAMinNum.value = "";
  PointAMaxNum.value = "";
  PointBMinNum.value = "";
  PointBMaxNum.value = "";
  PointCMinNum.value = "";
  PointCMaxNum.value = "";
  PointDMinNum.value = "";
  PointDMaxNum.value = "";
  PointFMinNum.value = "";
  PointFMaxNum.value = "";

  // removes everything that user added
  const removePointAssignmentDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.point-assignment');
  removePointAssignmentDiv.forEach(div => div.remove());

  nextBtn.innerText = "Next";
  nextBtn.type = "button";

  pointGradeForm.classList.toggle("hidden");
  cgNameInput.classList.toggle("hidden");
  cgFormContainer.classList.toggle("hidden");
  addCurrentGradeClassBtn.classList.toggle("hidden");
};

addPointsBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {

  const createAssignmentDiv = document.createElement("div");
  createAssignmentDiv.className = "point-assignment";

  const createNameLabel = document.createElement("label");
  createNameLabel.textContent = "Name (Optional): ";

  const createNameInput = document.createElement("input");
  createNameInput.type = "text";

  const createPointInput = document.createElement("input");
  createPointInput.type = "number";
  createPointInput.placeholder = "Points Received";
  createPointInput.className = "point-input";

  createAssignmentDiv.appendChild(createNameLabel);
  createAssignmentDiv.appendChild(createNameInput);
  createAssignmentDiv.appendChild(createPointInput);

  // Insert the new assignment div after the the pointText
  pointText.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", createAssignmentDiv);

});


currentGradeCalculator.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  addOrUpdatePointsForm();
});
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css">

<main>
  <h1>Calculator</h1>
  <div class="home-container">
    <button class="home-btn"><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></button>
  </div>
  <div class="current-grade-calculator">
    <p id="current-grade-text" class="hidden">Which Grading System</p>
    <div id="add-class-btn" class="hidden">
      <button id="add-class-current-grade" type="button">Add New Class</button>
    </div>
    <div id="choose-grading-system" class="choose-grading-system hidden">
      <button id="point-system-btn" type="button">Points System</button>
      <button id="percentage-system-btn" type="button">Percentage System</button>
    </div>
    <div id="cg-name-input" class="hidden">
      <label for="current-grade-name" class="label-name">Name (Optional)</label>
      <input type="text" class="name-input" id="current-grade-name" value="" />
    </div>
    <form id="point-grade-form" class="hidden">
      <div id="point-system-input">
        <div class="grade-point-input">
          <div class="grade-row">
            <label for="a-input">A:</label>
            <input type="number" id="point-a-min-number" min="0" placeholder="Minimum Points" required/>
            <input type="number" id="point-a-max-number" min="1" placeholder="Maximum Points" required>
          </div>
          <div class="grade-row">
            <label for="b-input">B:</label>
            <input type="number" id="point-b-min-number" min="0" placeholder="Minimum Points" required/>
            <input type="number" id="point-b-max-number" min="1" placeholder="Maximum Points" required>
          </div>
          <div class="grade-row">
            <label for="c-input">C:</label>
            <input type="number" id="point-c-min-number" min="0" placeholder="Minimum Points" required/>
            <input type="number" id="point-c-max-number" min="1" placeholder="Maximum Points" required>
          </div>
          <div class="grade-row">
            <label for="d-input">D:</label>
            <input type="number" id="point-d-min-number" min="0" placeholder="Minimum Points" required/>
            <input type="number" id="point-d-max-number" min="1" placeholder="Maximum Points" required>
          </div>
          <div class="grade-row">
            <label for="f-input">F:</label>
            <input type="number" id="point-f-min-number" min="0" placeholder="Minimum Points" required/>
            <input type="number" id="point-f-max-number" min="1" placeholder="Maximum Points" required>
          </div>
          <p id="point-text">Add Up The Points You Gotten</p>
        </div>
        <div class="next-container">
          <button id="point-next-btn" type="button">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div class="cg-close-btn">
          <button id="point-cancel-btn" type="button">Cancel</button>
        </div>
        <div id="adding-point-container">
          <button id="add-points-btn" type="button">Add Points</button>
        </div>
        <div id="know-grade-container">
          <button id="know-grade-btn" type="button">Know My Points</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div id="form-container">
      <!-- holds the new form user submits -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <dialog id="closing-tab-confirm">
    <form method="dialog">
      <p class="closing-message">Unsaved Changes</p>
      <p class="closing-message">Delete?</p>
      <div class="yes-or-no-btn">
        <button id="cg-yes" type="button" class="btn">Yes</button>
        <button id="cg-no" type="button" class="btn">No</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </dialog>
</main>




Too much code in your question to debug. Reduce it to a [mcve] please.

Is localStorage important to the problem? It prevents the snippet from running, so if you can remove that code it would help us see the problem.
